# Assertion error when using pushViewController to a TableViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, segue, pushviewcontroller

I am trying to transition from a view controller to a table view controller programmatically (vs. with a storyboard segue), using this code:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:photosTVC animated:YES];
```

However, I get an "assertion error" when the table view controller is loading; specifically, on the second line of this method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Photo";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
...
```

The table view controller loads fine when transitioning to it using a segue, but just not when I transition this way.  Any ideas I could try would be much appreciated!

Thanks for reading.

EDIT:  The full error text is below:

Assertion failure in -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2372/UITableView.m:4460

Comment: What is the complete error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];` the cell has to be registered using `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:` or `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` which is done for you if you're using storyboard.

So use just this method, `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]` when you're doing it programatically unless there are specific reasons not to.

EDIT:

```
UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    // or whatever cell initialisation method you have / created
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  As I do need access to indexPath later in the method, it looks like I'll need to implement registerNib/registerClass.  If I still need to preserve functionality when transitioning with a segue, should I implement both register methods?

Comment: even if you only use [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier], you still have access for indexPath later, tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: still gives you the indexPath. You'll implement registerNib/registerClass depends on what you're doing, are you creating a subclass of UITableViewCell, or you just prototype the cell using NIB files, but I still think you can get away with just [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier].

Comment: OK, by using just that method, the original error is now gone.  Thanks!  However, it does trip up here:  Assertion failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2372/UITableView.m:5471

Comment: OK, that's great—it works.  The table view does successfully appear, so that answers my original question.  The UIBarButtonItem and segue that I had setup in storyboard no longer work when I transition programmatically... I'm starting to see the disadvantages of using storyboards (or at least in the way that I'm using them).